# Populating a JTable in REST web services, Jersey

Tags: java, json, rest, jtable, jersey

I want to populate a JTable with data of a database table in the Server. I have retrieved the data as follows to the client side.

```
ClientResponse response = service.path("access").path("loadtable").queryParams(pathParams).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(ClientResponse.class);
    String responseString = response.getEntity(String.class);
```

How can I populate the JTable using the above output? I know I can use the DefaultTableModel to input data if I have a Object List. But it does not seem an option since I have a String and the Object List was created in the Server Side and then passed to the client side via JSON.